# Pass variable from route to controller in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5

Is there any way to pass the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable to the controller in Laravel 5?

Comment: 'Pass' from where? Isn't `$_SERVER` a PHP global variable and therefore available from anywhere?

Comment: pass from routes.php to controller. I need to know what was the URL in routes.php before it was sumbitted to controller.

Comment: As I said, the `$_SERVER` won't change. You can access it from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `$_SERVER` right away, or use a more 'laravelish' way with the proper request wrapper: `Request::server('REQUEST_URI')` or `$request->getRequestUri()`

Answer (score 1):

**My solution is only valid if you do not explicitly require $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], to be honest i find this method simpler and easier to use as well.**

Well if you want to pass a variable from a URL theres much easier ways. If you pass a url in a laravel blade page like this...

```
<a href="/details/{{ $id }}/{{ $firstname }}">Pass Details</a>
```

you can then access the variables simply from the route and then send them to a controller.

```
Route::get('/details/{id}/{firstname}', 'PagesController@ThisMethod');
```

The variable are now stored as $id and $firstname and can now be accessed from your controller, lastly in your controller you can do what you want with these variables.

```
public function ThisMethod($id, $firstname){
    dd($id, $firstname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `$request` variable to your controller function. This variable contains all info you need about the request, including the route.

For example:

```
Route::get('/test/url', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    dd($request->getRequestUri());
});
```

Will output

```
"/test/url"
```

For more info about the request variable you can visit [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests).

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel is using Symfony's **HttpFoundation** component to manage Request/Response flow.

It provides useful functions to fetch server variables. Just add `$request`variable as an argument to your controller function & then access using:

1. $request->getRequestUri() //Returns the requested URI (path and query string).
2. $request->getUri() //Generates a normalized URI (URL) for the Request.

For other functions, please refer: http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html